# How are the 5 questions shown on "Visit meta" selected?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm curious how it's determined which questions appear there. I checked meta, and it's neither **hot** nor **active**. I used [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the featured tag causes a question to be featured on the meta house ad.

The featured tag will be auto-stripped from any post after 30 days to prevent too much staleness.

The rest is driven from the weekly tab, and if any room is left over (there are only 5 slots), the hot tab.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7046/revisions has had the `featured` tag for months for example

Comment: @kop only applies to per-site metas not meta.so